# Spring Security auto CSRF token creation is not working on Firefox

Tags: spring, rest, firefox, csrf

When I upload a file through my app that uses Spring framework and spring security, it sends a CSRF token in the request through Spring to prevent CSRF. This token does not seem to be generated as it's left out of the request URL in Firefox. Again, this is happening in Firefox only. Does anyone have any experience with this and/or have any insight as to why this is happening? I've tried accepting cookies from this website in the browser and doing a few hacks in my code to allow it, but none of it seems to work. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, it turns out that my async call to retrieve a new CSRF token wasn't firing on time and the form would post without it, hence causing this error message from Spring. Check if you're posting the form prematurely if you're getting this error.